# Blender GLB file is not casting shadow

Tags: javascript, 3d, blender, shadow, react-three-fiber

I try to have a shadow on the plane under a building but somehow the material of blender glb are not reacting with the plane.

This is the code :

```js
export default function Test() {
  function Wall() {
    const modelGLB = useLoader(GLTFLoader, "./assets/glb/scene.glb");
    modelGLB.scene.children.forEach((mesh, i) => {
      mesh.castShadow = true;
      mesh.receiveShadow = true;
      mesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    });

    modelGLB.castShadow = true;
    modelGLB.scene.castShadow = true;

    return (
      <primitive castShadow object={modelGLB.scene} position={[0, 2, 0]} />
    );
  }

  function Plane() {
    return (
      <mesh
        receiveShadow
        rotation={[Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, 0]}
        position={[0, -1, 0]}
      >
        <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[600, 600]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" />
      </mesh>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ButtonBoundingBoxDoor />
      <ButtonBoundingBoxWall />
      <ButtonBoundingBoxWindow />
      <div className={styles.ViewModel}>
        <Canvas
          shadows
          className={styles.frame3D}
          camera={{ position: [40, 40, 40] }}
        >
          <directionalLight
            castShadow
            shadow-mapSize-height={512}
            shadow-mapSize-width={512}
            shadow-Bias={-0.05}
            intensity={1}
            position={[15, 50, 7]}
          />

          <Wall />
          <Box castShadow position={[1, 1, 7]}>
            <meshLambertMaterial castShadow />
          </Box>
          <gridHelper args={[400, 150, 0xe8ca63, 0xc4dad8]} />
          <Plane />
        </Canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I parese thought the blend fiel and turn the castShadow on but it react not on the plane.
Do i have export files from Blender different or how can I turn shadow on at the material